# Laravel / Eloquent eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This will be an easy question for some, but I can't seem to find the answer online or in the documentation (only variants of it which I don't want).

- Lets say we have a `Question` class
- Each `Question` object can optionally have multiple `Tag`s

I have set the classes up and things behave as expected. Currently I use:

- `$questions = Question::all();`

This works as expected, however it does not eager load.

To be clear: `$question->tags` gives the array I am expecting. There is not a relationship problem.

Due to new requirements I will be creating a view with possibly thousands of questions, so this eager loading is a must.

I attempted to use:

- `$questions = Question::with('tag')->all();`

Which gives error message:

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2345: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()

Every tutorial, or way I google eager loading, either specifies an ID, OR is a tutorial on how to ONLY show parents with children.

I simple want "all and their children".

This has got to be easy.. does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks
Rick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define the method in your model. As far as I see you're going to have one to many relationship. And that's going to be

```
class Question extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

Tag class

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Question');
    }
}
```

And the controller. Instead of `all()` use `get()` method.

```
$questions = Question::with('tags')->get();
```

As I defined `tags` method in the `Question` model. `Question::with('tags')` should call it. Instead, if you're going to do `Question::with('tag')`, `tag` method should be defined in `Question` model.

Notice the **s**

Comment: These are already defined. This is not the step I am having a problem with. To be clear.. I can already correctly query from the objects. $question->tags gives me an array.. it's just that it is LAZY loaded. I want to enforce an EAGER load.

Comment: `$questions = Question::with('tag')->get();` gives: `BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2345: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tag()`

Comment: `$questions = Question::with('tags')->get();` (it should be tags not tag = to the function name inside the Question model)

Comment: Thanks to a rep increase, this has now been marked as correct. To be clear: it was a 'tag'/'tags' pluralisation issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've marked both answers as correct: the original syntax suggested is correct, and the class name issue raised was the final issue.
Thanks all:

`$questions = Question::with('tags')->get();`