# How to output Eloquent Eager Loading in View (blade files) in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

I have a question related to this LINK:

**[Laravel / Eloquent eager loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688962/laravel-eloquent-eager-loading/53181986)**

Can you help me with the output in blade now with this? I implement this eloquent relation and add this in controller correctly, But how to output this in view now - in blade file!?

Can you write a little code for this example Comments - Tags. If we want to show that in a blade. To see this like child's into parents in some way.?

For example to output Questions and related tags what belongs in particular question. Like for example: Question1 [ Tag1 - Tag4 - Tag12 ] - - - Question2 [ Tag1 Tag 8 Tag5 ] ... and so on, like in some tree in view like in olx we see categories inside that it shows subcategories. olx.com.om/en.
Or another example when we have: COUNTRIES AND CATEGORIES (MANY TO MANY RELATION), and want to list CATEGORIES in view above, and countries that belong to particular category below.

Thanks in advance, 
I am new to laravel want to start my own blog I am learning laravel for 2 + months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller function, will look like this.

```
$questions = Question::with('tags')->get();

$title = "List of questions";

return view('test', compact('questions', 'title'));
```

In your blade will look like this and see how the tags relationships being called.

```
   <!-- ouput: List of questions-->
    <h2> {{ $title }} </h2>

    <!-- ouput:list of questions -->
    @foreach($questions as $question) 
       Question Name : {{ $question->name }}

        <b> Tags: </b> 
        @foreach($question->tags as $tag) 
              {{ $tag->name }} 
        @endforeach

    @endforeach
```

That's how you output the data to your blade file. Hope that gives you an idea.

Comment: Thanks very much Jesus, you give me and idea of sure. I am glade to have support from you.

Just to mention: I implement this now and everything is working well, but I play a little and try to write in controller without " with('tags') " in this way: $questions = Question::get(); or $questions = Question::all(); ||| and it is working as well as with this " with('tags') " - the same. I am using Laravel 5.7 , and many to many realationship !!

Is that correct ?

.......Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am glad that it helps, yes your doing correctly. If you like you can also connect me through skype id: jesus.erwin.suarez143

Comment: Thanks Jesus, Ok I will. Thank you. :) I just have a doubt how it output tags inside the questions correctly when I write the function without " with('tags') ", and output this in blade in way you tell me. Why it is working without " with('tags') " in the same way like when I add " with('tags') " ? Is it important to add " with('tags') ". I am using elouqent model many to many relationship, belongstoMany for both of models and laravel 5.7. Is it working maybe because I am using laravel 5.7 or ? Thanks

Comment: P.S. I just see with debuggar that I have more queries when use without with('tags') instead with it.

Comment: Correct, you will have more queries when your not using with('') because every time you call the relationship attributes it requires a db query in order to return a specific response.

Comment: Thanks Jesus,

I have new doubt if you can help me I ll be very thankful to you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199509/how-to-eager-load-the-user-function-from-eloquent-relationship-previously-set